# Can Ubuntu use fringe wifi and mobile broadband at the same time

Tags: wireless

I'm wondering if Ubuntu 18.04 can use a fringe Wi-Fi open connection to the Internet and mobile broadband that's limited to 5kib/s at the same time ...

I want to use both -- the fringe wifi can have alot more throughput but drops out for more than 5min at a time and mobile broadband is throttled ... and i dont want apt upgrade or other D/L to loose what they have downloaded already AND keep trying to get the update/upgrade going untill finished ...

Answer (score 1):

No. When you transmit a packet, the routing tables pick a single destination.